# Exception when running large INSERT query with mysql2

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2

I use `mysql2` package to run queries against MySQL server

Here are the connection settings

```
getConnection: function () {


   let host = "hostname.com";
   let database = "database_name";
   let username = "username";
   let password = "pwd";


   let con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: host,
      user: username,
      password: password,
      database: database,
      connectTimeout: 15000
   });

   return con;
},
```

It works fine for all queries excepts `INSERT` query with 26 parameters:

```
    recordCreate: function (con, param1, param2,
       param3,  param4,  param5,  param6,  param7,
       param8,  param9,  param10, param11, param12,
       param13, param14, param15, param16, param17,
       param18, param19, param20, param21, param22,
       param23, param24, param25, param26, callback) {
       try {
         con.connect(function (err, result) {
                 try {
                      if (err) throw err;
                      con.query(“INSERT INTO tbldata (param1,
                           param2,  param3,  param4,  param5,  param6,
                           param7,  param8,  param9,  param10, param11,
                           param12, param13, param14, param15, param16,
                           param17, param18, param19, param20, param21,
                           param22, param23, param24, param25, param26
                   ) VALUES 
                   (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                    ?)”,[param1,  param2,  param3,  param4,  param5,
                         param6,  param7,  param8,  param9,  param10,
                         param11, param12, param13, param14, param15,
                         param16, param17, param18, param19, param20,
                         param21, param22, param23, param24, param25,
                         param26]
       , function (err) {
          try {
             if (err) throw err;
             callback(true);
          } catch (err) {
             callback(err);
          } finally {
             con.close();
          }
  });
```

I keep gettin the following error message:

> C:\MyProjects\TMS\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:30
>           this.onResult(err);
>                ^
>
> TypeError: this.onResult is not a function
>       at Query.execute (C:\MyProjects\TMS\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:30:14)
>       at Connection.handlePacket (C:\MyProjects\TMS\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:449:32)
>       at PacketParser.Connection.packetParser.p [as onPacket] (C:\MyProjects\TMS\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:72:12)
>       at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\MyProjects\TMS\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:76:16)
>       at Socket.Connection.stream.on.data (C:\MyProjects\TMS\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:79:25)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:13)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
>       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:17)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

It is important to state that those data elements (parameters) are really small. We talk here about short 10 chars strings and digits

For example

```
INSERT INTO tbldata (param1,  param2,  param3,  param4,  param5,
                     param6,  param7,  param8,  param9,  param10,
                     param11, param12, param13, param14, param15,
                     param16, param17, param18, param19, param20,
                     param21, param22, param23, param24, param25,
                     param26) VALUES 
                    (51, 'Test 51', '', '2019-12-01', '2019-12-01',
                      1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                      0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3);
```

I tried to run the example query on the MySQL server and it works fine

Comment: Have you tried narrowing that query down to less parameters? Where does it start to go wrong?

Comment: Means nothing to me `TypeError: this.onResult is not a function at Query.execute` but surley it should mean something to a node person

Comment: @NicoHaase, yes, but probably not enough. I removed two parameters. No success. I shall probably keep narrowing it. To be honest, I thought that this is a well-known issue with either ``mysql2`` or ``MySQL`` server variables

Comment: @RiggsFolly, can it be somehow related to ``MAX_PACKET_LENGT``?

Comment: THe issue looks more like a node.js syntax issue rather than an SQL issue.

Comment: @Martin, I tend to agree with you. I'm narrowing the query as ``Nico Haase`` suggested

Comment: @Martin, you were right, it was a syntax issue. Solved.

Comment: @IgorM please write an answer if you know what the answer was. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After narrowing the query I realized that it was a stupid syntax issue. I'd like to thank `Nico Haase` and `Martin` for the help with my "brainstorming".

I appreciate the `mysql2` team's job. I also hope that they will address the issue with `query` method getting more than 2 parameters.

```
con.query("INSERT INTO tbldata (" +
                                "param1, " +
                                "param2, " +
                                "param3, " +
                                "param4, ", -- here is the syntax issue. Comma instead of plus
                                "param5) VALUES (?, ?, " +
                                "?, ?, " +
                                "?, ?, " +
                                "?)",
                                [param1,
                                    param2,
                                    param3,
                                    param4,
                                    param5]
```

Comment: I'd recommend using object as single parameter or named placeholders. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row and https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Extras.md#named-placeholders